# How to attach JS EventListeners for AJAX responses without recursion?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently having a hard time to figure out how to reattach `EventListeners` for an HTML fragment that gets received via `XHR` and then inserted to the DOM. I will try to reduce the code for brevity.

When the site loads the first time, the html looks like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="password-change">
    <form id="password-change-form">
      <input id="new-password" type="password" name="newPassword">
      <input type="submit" value="Change">
    </form>
  </div>

  <script>new PasswordChangeForm();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The `PasswordChangeForm` will do some preparation:

```js
class PasswordChangeForm {

  constructor() {
    this.initValidation();
  }

  initValidation() {

    this._form = document.querySelector("#password-change-form");
    this._fields = [
      {
        node: this._form.querySelector("#new-password"),
        validator: Validators.isValidPassword
      }
    ];

    /* Arrow function to gain access to initValidation() without extra binding effort. */
    this._relay = event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const section = document.querySelector("#password-change");
      const form = document.querySelector("#password-change-form");

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const actionUrl = event.target.action;
      const payload = new FormData(form);

      const xhrLoadHandler = event => {
        section.parentNode.replaceChild(xhr.response.querySelector("#password-change"), section);

        /* !!! HERE is the root of the RECURSION problem: !!! */
        this.initValidation();  /* validation must be initialized again for the newly imported form */
      };

      xhr.addEventListener("load", xhrLoadHandler, false);
      xhr.open("POST", actionUrl, true);
      xhr.responseType = "document";
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html");
      xhr.send(payload);
    };

   const formValidator = new FormValidator(this._form, this._fields, this._relay);
  }
}
```

and then instantiates a FormValidator, which checks the input fields and in case everything's allright, it sends the form through the _relay() function and receives the form back from the server, where the newly received form may have some additional comments.

The FormValidator looks like that:

```js
class FormValidator {

    constructor(form, fields, relay) {
        this._form = form;
        this._fields = fields;
        this._relay = relay;

        this.addListeners();
    }

    addListeners() {
        this._form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
            if (!this.validateForm()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            }

            this._relay(event);
        });
    }

    validateForm() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The flow goes like this:

1. The PasswordChangeForm gets instantiated and initialized for the current DOM (the required nodes).
2. The FormValidator gets instantiated and passed properties which contain DOM nodes as well as a function called `_relay`.
3. After the validation is done, the _relay function does the `XHR`.
4. When the response is received, the code fragmet containing the new form replaces the old form.
5. And now we have to somehow reinitialize the PasswordChangeForm to have the newly received form listening for validation events again: this is currently done within the _relay function, where the function calls `initValidation()`. **Unfortunately, the _relay function sits inside the initValidation function.**
6. So finally, reinitializing this way bloats the call stack every time the user sends the form.

Practically this seems to be no big problem for this specific case, since I don't think a user will send a password change form many times. **However, I really want to get rid of this recursion.**

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Comment: *When the response is received, the code fragmet containing the new form replaces the old form.*: What's the difference between the old and new forms? I believe if you can eliminate this replacement, you don't have to re-run `initValidation()`.

Comment: Unfortunetely I can't eliminate this replacement. It will always come back a complete segement containing the more or less same form which has to replace the old one.

Comment: If it's the same form, why bother replacing at all? Regardless of what's returned, couldn't you skip that step in your callback?

Comment: No, I can't. And therefore I'm searching for a proper solution.

Comment: Use event delegation?

Comment: @VLAZ I haven't heard about that yet. I will read into it and see if it may help to solve the problem. Many thanks for this advice.

Comment: [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296) | [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203198)

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, I think this will work. I have to rewrite a bunch of code, but it seems, that this is the proper way to go. If I'd only knew this a few weeks ago, it would spare me from refactoring the all the validation thingies - but its never too late to learn ;). Will get a place in my toolbox, thanks again.